# How to put an error message in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

How to put an error message in the dropdown list if the dropdown is there's no option selected after submit button clicked using JavaScript?

EDIT: Dropdown have an error message after the submit button clicked. But How to customize the message?

I've got the following form with dropdown: https://jsfiddle.net/6jgyfzeo/2/

```
 <form id="form" onsubmit="return(login())">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/><input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name"
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')"
oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />
<input name="pass"  type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
 <select name="birth_M" id="birth_M">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Month</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the select tag an id (I gave it the id 'birth_M'), then insert this jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) { //catches the submit event
     if(!$('#birth_M').val()){ //check if select got any value
       alert( "You Error message" );
       return;  
     }
  });
});
```

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/453/

Comment: I see you've added a function on submit called "login". can you post it's code?

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush and couldn't give a full answer.
Check the new answer I've edited. Should work

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `required` attribute to make the list required.The required attribute also workd with `select` tag.
It will look like this:

```
<select name="birth_M" id="birth_M" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Month</option>
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add required to the selectlist.
Working JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/MFasseur/woth5t6s/

```
 <form id="form" onsubmit="return(login())">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/><input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />
  <input name="pass"  type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
  <select name="birth_M" id="birth_M" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What you could do is download the localization files here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization

Or do it in javascript:
$("#form").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "This is my custom required message"
        }
    });

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **PHP** to show your own error message instead of using **Javascript**:

```
<?php
if(empty($_REQUEST['birth_M']))
{
 echo "You must select something from the list first1";
};
?>
```